# cocoa touch: touch on view 'A' resulting in updating view 'B', how to realize this?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

Within my app there are two view-classes: UIViewA and UIViewB. In the Storyboard I have connected these classes to two different view-areas on the  same view controller.
I need to update UIViewB on a 'touchbegan' message in UIViewA. This must be possible but I can not find the instancename for the views nor does a [super setNeedsDisplay] function.
Can anyone give me the propper way to deal with this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup outlets to the views? Once you have outlets setup then you can use code to access them. They will show up as properties in your view controller.

Comment: I have no outlets setup, sounds interessting. Where can I find how to do this? Any code snippets?

Comment: Here is a great tutorial to get you started if you are new. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Thank you very much. It is of great help.